# How to seamlessly use “” for English and „“ for German on a Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I am on a Mac using the `U.S. International – PC` keyboard layout, mostly for its ability seamlessly to type accented German (`ä`, `ö`, `ü`) and French (`à`, `é`, `è`, `ê`, ...) letters.

It is easy to type English quotation marks `""` (non-typographical) or `“”` (typographical) but seems impossible to get German quotation marks `„“` on this keyboard. I have been exploring the Settings without success.

How can I write German quotation marks on a `U.S. International – PC` keyboard on a Mac? If it’s not possible, which keyboard layout can I use that allows for both English and German-style quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need US-PC for this.

Regular US [or UK too] have all the accents under dead keys  - so the only thing you're gaining are the two 'enforced live' keys, which removes your ability to use those keys normally.

I can only show this with images of a UK ISO keyboard, on a US ANSI the key left of z migrates up to left of 1.

Standard dead keys, under  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> 
[image]

'enforced live' keys [the dead keys are still present in this layout too]
[image]

In either case, your German 'real' opening quotes „ are on  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>w</kbd> , closing quotes “ on  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd> 
*From comments* - German actually uses the 'English' open quote to close, which is on the same key, just  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>[</kbd>  instead of adding  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of Opt ⌥ Shift ⇧ w.

Comment: Not quite right but close, Opt ⌥ Shift ⇧ ] produces a ” but the correct closing quote would be “. I do not know any typography, but my spelling tool suggests using the correct version which is rotated by 180 degree (wide at bottom, narrow at the top). Opt ⌥ ] seems to be the correct one?

Comment: Hmmm… I hadn't realised that German uses the international 'open quote' as its close quote. Added to answer.